# Dad, you think or Dad, do you think (?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I wrote the next sentence:
"Oh Dad, you think my room is a mess? You should see my life". But then I remembered that in questions obviously you have to put the verb "be", and the doubt came, is the sentence correct or I should write; "oh dad, do you think my room is a mess? You should see my life. 
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Surely you're not asking the ELU community to proofread, or worse, complete a school assignment for you?

Comment: I'd consider the first variant far better here (if you substitute a more sensible vocative, a person who hardly knows you). It's obviously an echo question, a response to a remark, so 'Do you ...' hardly fits.

Comment: Rob Steel, I wasn't asking help for finish my assignment. I actually had the boubt cause sometimes I get confuse for the grammar I'm learning it.

Answer (score 0):

The fictional conversation seems stilted to me, at best, as this character is speaking to their father. How very unlikely, then, that the character would say "you should see my life"! Wouldn't the father know something about the character's life?

But let us say you resolve that issue. Either construction is perfectly acceptable in modern US English usage. The construction "you think" may not technically be correct, but it is so common in everyday oral communication that it feels entirely comfortable. My grammar teacher 50 years ago would have quibbled on this. I don't think you would find a teacher today even blinking over such usage.